# Concatenate 3 unidimensional arrays together in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

I'm leaving MatLab for numpy and in general it's going ok, but I'm having a nightmare finding a nice pythonic way to do what would have done this in MatLab:

```
A=[1.0;2.0;3.0;4.0] %Column vector
B=[5.0;6.0;7.0;8.0] %Another one
C=[A,B,B] %4 x 3 matrix
```

In Python, setting up A like so:

```
A=np.array([1,2,3,4])
B=np.array([5,6,7,8])
```

And concatenating like so:

```
C=np.concatenate((A,B,B),axis=1)
```

Stacks them one on top of the other, and _C, hstack etc fail as well. I'm guessing I need a nice pyythonic way of turning a (4,) numpy array into a (4,1) array. In my code these vectors are much bigger than this and are created dynamically so I can't just type:

```
A=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.c_[A,B,B]`, which gives

```
array([[1, 5, 5],
       [2, 6, 6],
       [3, 7, 7],
       [4, 8, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll add something on which is quicker out of this and atomh33ls approach once I profile my code.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)

```
>>> A=np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> B=np.array([5,6,7,8])
>>> np.dstack((A, B, B))
array([[[1, 5, 5],
        [2, 6, 6],
        [3, 7, 7],
        [4, 8, 8]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> C=np.array([A,B,B])
>>> C
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

or:

```
>>> C=np.array([A,B,B]).swapaxes(1,0)
>>> C
array([[1, 5, 5],
       [2, 6, 6],
       [3, 7, 7],
       [4, 8, 8]])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'll add something on which is quicker out of this and Christoph's approach once I profile my code.